# Android Simulate Back Button in PrefferenceFragment

Tags: android

I've added a Cancel and OK button to the bottom of my PreferenceFragment screen, but I can't figure out how to return to the previous screen when they are clicked. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onClickListener You should get parent activity which host your PreferenceFragment and remove that PreferenceFragment by the standard way.

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(preferencesFragment).commit();
```

preferencesFragment is reference to your PreferencesFragment.

Comment: Well, that closes the screen, but it doesn't go back to the previous screen, it just leaves a blank screen.

Comment: Figured out what I wanted: `getActivity().finish();`